# SQL Query - Get distinct count of two tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, charts

Table 1(student_details)

Is having 532 datas with different advisor each data is assigned to one advisor like

```
    id advisor
    -- -------
    1  Bala
    2  Shanmugam
    3  Priya
    4 Bala
   etc..
```

Similaly in table 2:training_details

```
        id advisor
        -- -------
        1  Bala

       etc..
```

I tried this query this will return count of people assigned to each advisor alone from table1.I just want to count from two tables and select advisor

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.advisor as advisor,IFNULL(COUNT(t2.advisor), 0) AS total  FROM advisor AS t1 
LEFT JOIN student_details AS t2 ON t1.advisor = t2.advisor AND t2.del!=1 GROUP BY t1.advisor;
```

Similarly I Just want to join two table entry and return distinct advisor with equal count in 2columns;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT advisor, COUNT(*) as TheCount
FROM
    (
     SELECT advisor FROM table 1
     UNION ALL
     SELECT advisor FROM table 2
     ) AS [TheNames]
GROUP BY advisor
```

or

```
SELECT x.advisor, COUNT(x.advisor)
    FROM (SELECT advisor
            FROM table1
          UNION ALL
          SELECT advisor
            FROM table2
         ) x
GROUP BY x.advisor
```

Comment: Here U didnt specify anythng about second table

Comment: Ya I got the result.Is there anyway to add Where clause in this query

Comment: after selection  from  table u can use ...@KavyaShree

Comment: If I choose year It will show count include with that year

Comment: In both of the table there will be date column so if the data belong to that particular column value it will retrieve that column alone

Comment: yes that year u need to include in both tables and also in group by also ..@KavyaShree